# I am receiving an error about incompatible type: Sort cannot be converted to java.util.arraylist<java.lang.Integer>

Tags: java

In my main method I am receiving the error message incompatible type.
 I have created a printList method to print the output. I believe the problem has something to do with this method but so far I can not figure it out.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sort 
{
/*  fun printList list =
              let
                val counter = ref 0
                val temp = ref ""
                val n = length(list)
              in
                while (!counter < n) do 
                  ( temp := !temp ^ (Int.toString(List.nth(list,!counter))^" ");
                  counter := !counter+1);
                temp := !temp ^ "\n";
                !temp 
              end;
*/

    public static String printList (ArrayList<Integer> left)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        String temp = "";
        int n = left.size();

        while(counter < n)
        {
            temp += left.get(counter)+ " ";
            counter += 1;

        }

        temp += "\n";

        return temp;

    }

/*

            fun lineList file =
              let
                val instr = TextIO.openIn file
                val str   = TextIO.input instr
              in 
                String.tokens (fn x => x = #",")str
              before
                TextIO.closeIn instr
              end;

*/

    public ArrayList<Integer> lineList(String file) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            int i = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                tmp.add(scanner.nextInt());
                i++;
            }
            scanner.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }

/*

            fun halve nil = (nil, nil)  
            |   halve [a] = ([a], nil)
            |   halve (a :: b :: cs) =
                  let
                    val (x, y) = halve cs
                  in
                    (a :: x, b :: y)
                  end;
*/
    public static ArrayList<Integer> halve(ArrayList<Integer> l, String subL){
        int halveSize = l.size() / 2;
        ArrayList<Integer> halfList = new ArrayList<Integer>(halveSize);
        if(subL == "left"){
            for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i += 2){
                halfList.add(l.get(i));
            }
        }else if(subL == "right"){
            for(int i = 1; i < l.size(); i += 2){
                halfList.add(l.get(i));
            }
        }
        return halfList;
    }

/*
            fun merge (nil, ys) = ys
            |   merge (xs, nil) = xs
            |   merge (x :: xs, y :: ys) =
                  if (x > y) then x :: merge(xs, y :: ys)
                  else y :: merge(x :: xs, ys);

*/

     public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> le, ArrayList<Integer> r) {
         ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;
         while (i < le.size() && j < r.size()) {
             if (le.get(i) <= r.get(j)) {
                 result.add(le.get(i));
                 i++;
             }else {
                 result.add(r.get(j));
                 j++;
             }

         }
         for (int k=0;k<le.size();k++) {
             if (k>i) {
                 result.add(le.get(k));
             }
         }
         for (int l=0;l<r.size();l++) {
             if (l>j) {
                 result.add(r.get(l));
             }
         }
         return result;
     }




/*

            fun mergeSort nil = nil
            |   mergeSort [a] = [a]
            |   mergeSort theList =
                  let
                    val (x, y) = halve theList
                  in
                    print("xList: "^printList(x));
                    print("yList: "^printList(y));
                    merge(mergeSort x, mergeSort y)
                  end;

*/

     public static ArrayList<Integer> mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> l){
        if(l.size() <= 1){
            return l;
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> xList = halve(l, "left");
        ArrayList<Integer> yList = halve(l, "right");
        System.out.print("xList: " +printList(xList));
        System.out.print("yList: " +printList(yList));
        return merge(mergeSort(xList), mergeSort(yList));
    }

/*
            fun quicksort nil = nil
            |   quicksort (pivot :: rest) =
                  let
                    fun split(nil) = (nil,nil)
                    |   split(x :: xs) =
                          let
                            val (below, above) = split(xs)
                          in
                            if x < pivot then (x :: below, above) 
                            else (below, x :: above)
                          end;
                    val (below, above) = split(rest)
                  in
                    quicksort below @ [pivot] @ quicksort above
                  end;

            val optList = map (fn str => (Int.fromString str)) (lineList "/home/chella/Documents/SMLCode1/input.txt");
            val intList = map Option.valOf optList;

            fun uselessMachine x = mergeSort(quicksort(x));

            uselessMachine(intList);

*/
    public static ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> input)
    {
        if(input.size() <= 1){
            return input;
        }

        int centre = input.get(0);

        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 1; i < input.size(); i++){
            if(input.get(i) < centre){
                a.add(input.get(i));
            }else{
                b.add(input.get(i));
            }
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> output = quickSort(a);
        output.add(centre);
        output.addAll(quickSort(b));

        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Sort <Integer>s= new Sort<Integer>();

        Sort s= new Sort ();
        //int [] a = {1,2,3,4,8,10};
        //System.out.println(s.printList(a));

        try {
            s.mergeSort(s.quickSort(s.lineList("input.txt")));
        System.out.println(printList(s)); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full error, as it appears, in your question.

Comment: The error message is fix But now my output is Sort@45da046 but it suppose to be a list of numbers

Answer (score 2):

Well the error message is pretty clear...

> Sort cannot be converted to java.util.arraylist

The problem is at this line :

```
System.out.println(printList(s));
```

`s` is an instance of `Sort` according to this initialization

```
Sort s = new Sort();
```

While the signature of `printList` is

```
public static String printList (ArrayList<Integer> left)
```

Which is suppose to receive an `ArrayList<Integer>` not a `Sort` object.

I think what you want to use is

```
System.out.println(printList(s.lineList("input.txt")));
```

This will fix the error.

**Edit :** Here is the snippet I was talking about in comments :

```
Sort s = new Sort();
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);
a.add(4);
a.add(8);
a.add(10);

System.out.println(printList(a));
```

Also if you want to print it in `reverse` order, then you will have to reverse the `list` using `Collections` package in the `printList` method which would now look like this :

```
public static String printList (ArrayList<Integer> left)
{
    int counter = 0;
    String temp = "";
    int n = left.size();
    Collections.reverse(left);

    while(counter < n)
    {
        temp += left.get(counter)+ " ";
        counter += 1;

    }

    temp += "\n";

    return temp;

}
```

the output would then be `10 8 4 3 2 1`

Comment: Thank you, It did fix the error but my output is Sort@45da046.. My output suppose to be numbers

Comment: Do you think i need to create a toString method to fix my output

Comment: it suppose to check  print the list of number in reverse.. Also i created a array list in my main method int [] a = {1,2,3,4,8,10}; System.out.println(printList(s.lineList(a))); And i am receiving the same error from before

Comment: @user2803053 You are doing multiple mistake here. First, `lineList` should receive a `String` which is the name of the `inputFile`. If you want to pass directly the `array` then you can skip the `s.lineList` part and directly do `System.out.printList(a))`.

Comment: Ok I get what did with with the object a and add it to the list and the reverse part as well make a lot of sense... My problem is with my text file input.txt.. It have numbers as well such as 4,3,2,1. I want to print out those numbers. Overtime I run the code I get Sort@45da046...

Comment: @user2803053 because you try to print the `Sort` object directly, what you get is it reference in memory. Use the code I gave in my answer and this will works.